# CPU usage and Memory status of Remote PC

Tags: c++, mfc, cpu

I am developing a Server Monitoring tool as MFC dialog based app.

I am trying to fetch the CPU status and memory status of some number of servers and draw a real time bar chart.

Is there any proper method by which I can periodically fetch this data (say 3 sec) for my graph.

Any method which help to fetch these data locally will also be helpful.

Comment: WMI: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512236(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here are some examples:

[Collecting Memory Usage Information For a Process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682050(v=vs.85).aspx)

[how to graph CPU usage in vc++](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?354912-how-to-graph-CPU-usage-in-vc)

Comment: Not for a single process, I need to know the total CPU usage of a particular server.